# Bug in a custom encryption/decryption program

Tags: encryption, python-3.5

I'm creating an encryption software in python 3.5. It should go along a key, using key[0] to shift raw[0], then key[1] to shift raw[1] etc, going back to key[0] when raw[i] is greater then key[i%len(key)].

```
# Converts the key into a numerical list. 
def convert(alph, key):
  for i in range(0, len(key)):
    rem = alph.index(key[i])
    numkey.append(rem)
    print(numkey)
  return numkey

#shifts the text dependant on the key
def encrypt (numkey, raw, alph):
  encr = ""
  emi = ()
  emi = list(emi)
  for i in range (0, len(raw)):
    rem = raw[i]
    rem = alph.index(rem)
    suba = i%len(numkey)
    ram = numkey[suba]
    shift = (rem + ram) % 28  #ensures that shift is an index of alph

    shift = alph[shift]
    emi.append(shift)
  for i in range(0, len(emi)):
    encr = encr + str(emi[i])
  print (encr)

letters = [
    ' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 
    'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 't', 's', 'u', 'v', 'w',
    'x', 'y', 'z', '.', ',', '!', '?']

raw_key = input("Please enter the key:\n")
raw_text = input("Please enter the text you would like to encrypt (no numbers or capitals):")
numkey = convert(letters, raw_key)
encrypt(numkey, raw_text, letters)
```

My problem is with the decryption program(below).

```
# Converts the key into a numerical list. 
def convert(alph, key):
  numkey = ()
  numkey = list(numkey)  # parse numkey as list
  for i in range(0, len(key)):
    rem = alph.index(key[i])
    numkey.append(rem)
  return numkey

# shifts the text dependant on the key
def encrypt (numkey,raw,alph):
  encr = ""
  emi = ()
  emi = list(emi)
  for i in range (0, len(raw)):
    rem = raw[i]
    rem = alph.index(rem)
    suba = i%len(numkey)
    ram = numkey[suba]
    shift = (rem - ram)

    if shift < 0:
        shift = shift + 28
    else:
        pass        
    shift = alph[shift]
    emi.append(shift)
  for i in range(0, len(emi)):
    encr = encr + str(emi[i])
  print (encr)

letters = [
    ' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 
    'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 't', 's', 'u', 'v', 'w',
    'x', 'y', 'z', '.', ',' ,'!' ,'?']

raw_key = input("Please enter the key:\n")
raw_text = input("Please enter the text you would like to decrypt:\n")
numkey = convert(letters, raw_key)
encrypt(numkey, raw_text, letters)
```

For some reason, after encrypting the characters ",", "?" & "!", if I pass them beck through the decryption they always returns as " ", "a" and "b" respectively. This isn't a problem with any other element in the characters list.

If anyone can spot the problem I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here in the encryption program:

```
shift = (rem + ram) % 28
```

The length of `letters` is 31 not 28. This is where you're looping back to the beginning of the array prematurely.

The problem is mirrored here in the decryption program:

```
shift = shift + 28
```

---

There are other problems as well. Just a few examples:

- In the encryption program `numkey` is not initialized in `convert()`
- no need to use `range()`, just use `for char in key:`
- no need for the `lst = ()` followed by `lst = list(lst)` pattern, just use a list in the first place, `lst = []`
- no checking for invalid characters
- function is still named `encrypt()` in the decryption program

Here's a quick first pass at cleaning both up.

Encryption:

```
import sys

LETTERS = (
    ' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
    'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 't', 's', 'u', 'v', 'w',
    'x', 'y', 'z', '.', ',', '!', '?')

# Converts the key into a numerical list.
def convert(alph, key):
  numkey = []
  for char in key:
    if char not in alph:
      sys.exit("Invalid character")
    numkey.append(alph.index(char))
  print(numkey)
  return numkey

# Shifts the text dependant on the key.
def encrypt (numkey, raw, alph):
  encr = ""
  for i, char in enumerate(raw):
    if char not in alph:
      sys.exit("Invalid character")
    rem = alph.index(char)
    ram = numkey[i % len(numkey)]
    # Ensure that shift is an index of alph
    shift = (rem + ram) % len(alph)
    encr = encr + alph[shift]
  print(encr)

raw_key = input("Please enter the key: ")
raw_text = input("Please enter the text you would like to encrypt (no numbers or capitals):\n")

numkey = convert(LETTERS, raw_key)
encrypt(numkey, raw_text, LETTERS)
```

Decryption:

```
import sys

LETTERS = (
    ' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
    'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 't', 's', 'u', 'v', 'w',
    'x', 'y', 'z', '.', ',' ,'!' ,'?')

# Converts the key into a numerical list.
def convert(alph, key):
  numkey = []
  for char in key:
    if char not in alph:
      sys.exit("Invalid character")
    numkey.append(alph.index(char))
  return numkey

# Shifts the text dependant on the key.
def decrypt(numkey, raw, alph):
  decr = ""
  for i, char in enumerate(raw):
    if char not in alph:
      sys.exit("Invalid character")
    rem = alph.index(char)
    ram = numkey[i % len(numkey)]
    shift = rem - ram
    if shift < 0:
        shift = shift + len(alph)
    decr = decr + alph[shift]
  print(decr)

raw_key = input("Please enter the key: ")
raw_text = input("Please enter the text you would like to decrypt:\n")

numkey = convert(LETTERS, raw_key)
decrypt(numkey, raw_text, LETTERS)
```